# I get a syntax error and an error saying illegal target for variable annotation. How do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Here I am trying to compare items from two lists and give a score based on who has the higher no at the given index. But I always shows syntax error in the first `elif` and says illegal target for variable annotation.

```
def comparetriplets(a, b):      

   p = 0                       
   q = 0                       
   x = 0                           
   while x < 3:
       if a[x] > b[x]:         
          p = 1               
          q = 0               
       x += 1                  
       elif b[x] > a[x]:       
          p = p+0             
          q = q+1             
       x += 1                  
       elif a[x] == b[x]:                          
          p = p+0             
          q = q+0             
       x += 1                  
return [p, q]
```

`elif b[x] > a[x]`: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `x += 1` is not properly indented...

Comment: Suggestion: You should install a linter in your IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to  write `x += 1` statement inside  `if block` and `elif block` like below:

```
def comparetriplets(a, b):
    p = 0                       
    q = 0                       
    x = 0                           
    while x < 3:
        if a[x] > b[x]:
            print('Begining of if :' , x)
            p = 1               
            q = 0               
            x += 1
            print('End of if :', x)
        elif b[x] > a[x]:
            print('Begining of elif-1 :' , x)
            p = p+0             
            q = q+1             
            x += 1
            print('End of elif-1 : ', x)
        elif a[x] == b[x]:    
            print('Begining of elif-2 : ' , x)
            p = p+0             
            q = q+0             
            x += 1
            print('End of elif-2 : ', x)
     return [p, q]
```

Please let me know if it clarifies your doubt or solves the syntax error.

Calling the function `comparetriplets`:

```
import numpy
import random
a = random.sample(range(1,51),4) # Generate a list of four random numbers
b = random.sample(range(1,51),4)

print(a)
print(b)
p,q = comparetriplets(a, b)
```

`Output`:

```
a : [32, 3, 27, 21]
b : [20, 8, 35, 37]
Begining of if : 0
End of if : 1
Begining of elif-1 : 1
End of elif-1 :  2
Begining of elif-1 : 2
End of elif-1 :  3
```

Comment: I want the value of x to increase by one after each time an if or elif condition is completed till the value of x = 2

Comment: @SarthakPandey: check the modified code with calling function code now. Let me know the difference between the original output and expected output.

Comment: Thank you, your code explained my doubt. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: @SarthakPandey: Please accept and like my answer if it cleared your doubt.

Comment: How do I do that? I am new here.

Comment: @SarthakPandey : [Link to accept and vote up an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I have just concluded a long and fruitless search for the meaning of "illegal target for variable notation".  But have come to the realization that the error message was trying to tell me that I had broken a sequence of 'if' and 'elif' statements, just as with the questioner's original code.  I had placed a temporary, unindented print statement after my initial 'if', which exited me from what should have been an 'if', 'elif' sequence.  The error message flagged the otherwise functional 'elif' statement, but the real problem was with the indentation of the earlier print statement.